# What would I see if I watched alien TV through a telescope?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Let's say I created a telescope so powerful that I could even see and perfectly track a television screen on a planet that orbits a distant star. Also assume that this star is moving at a high velocity relative to our sun and the mass of the other star is not equal to that of our sun. My understanding of relativity is that clocks on this alien world would move at a different rate relative to our clocks here on Earth.

If this is true, what would I "see" as I watched their television through this telescope in my time-frame (my real-time)? Would I see the show at a different rate (in slow-motion; or sped up)? Or, would the show appear normally to me, even though it is occurring in a completely different time-frame relative to mine?

Einstein is great for point to point thought experiments (Time A; Time B), but a continuous set of events does not seem to be so easily explained. Einstein could tell two parties exactly when to tune-in using their local clocks to see the start of an alien show, but what each would subsequently see seems less obvious to me.

Comment: *would the universe magically adjust everything* That really does make this a rather silly question.  If you think magic is required to avoid the effects of relativity, why ask ?

Comment: Why would you label this a "silly" question? Can you provide an answer: or just smug comments?I think "magically" perfectly sums up the continuous adjustments that the universe makes to present all observers with a consistent, continuous view of our universe. While smug; you comment does nothing to answer the original question.

Comment: As written your questions essentially ask this "Will I see time dilation effects when viewing a distant moving object ? " which has a simple "yes" answer and then asks "Or will magic change that ?" which, on this SE, will get an automatic "no".

Comment: If this is how a serious question is treated, I will refrain from asking any more. Great forum; thanks.

Comment: But you did not answer the question. What would time-dilation present to me? This has serious implications for ideas such as interstellar communication.

Comment: There is a rule on SE which means we expect people to do basic research before asking a question (it's the "homework-type" rule).  You could have answered these questions by simply doing that basic research.  Time dilation effects are explained on Wikipedia with more than enough detail for your questions.  Magic is not required.

Comment: *"but a continuous set of events does not seem to be so easily explained"* - the Lorentz transform (SR context here) takes one (inertial) coordinate system (a mapping of events to coordinates) to another, relatively moving coordinate system.  So, in this context, your statement quoted above is quite peculiar.  (As an aside, this site isn't a forum.  If you would like a *discussion*, there is our [h-bar chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) for that).

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with what one "sees", this involves the Doppler Effect.

For simplicity, consider the distant world moving with constant velocity.
Here's a spacetime diagram of the two worlds.
I've drawn it on rotated graph paper so that it's easy to visualize the ticks on each worldline. We assume that there is a standard unit of time.

To make the math simple, the distant world is moving with velocity (3/5)c.
Using triangle OPQ, Earth [in Red] measures Tatooine [in Blue] moving away with speed (3/5)c.
Using triangle OP'Q', Tatooine measures Earth moving away with speed (3/5)c.
It turns out that the corresponding Doppler factor is $\sqrt{\frac{1+(v/c)}{1-(v/c)}}=2$.

[image: Doppler effect on Rotated Graph Paper]

So, Tattooine transmissions emitted at 1-hour intervals (marking the start and end of an hour-long TV show on Tatooine) are received on Earth at 2-hour intervals. So, it would take you two-hours to watch one of their one-hour TV shows... it would look like everything was in slow motion.

Similarly, Earth transmissions emitted at 1-hour intervals are received on Tatooine at 2-hour intervals. So, it would take them two-hours to watch one of our one-hour TV shows....and would look like everything was in slow motion to them...

 in accord with the Principle of Relativity.

If, instead, we were approaching each other (so that v=(-3/5)c), the Doppler factor above would be (1/2) and 1-hour shows from one planet would be viewed by other planet in (1/2)-hour... and would look like everything was sped up.